# Hide all except the first 4 elements

Tags: css

There are endless elements. And I want to do is hide all except the first 4 elements. (with :not selector)

And I want to make a click all visible.. is this possible with css?

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>/*must hide*/
  <li></li>/*must hide*/
  <li></li>/*must hide*/
  <li></li>/*must hide*/
      ........ /*must hide foreva*/
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

```css
ul li:nth-child(n+5) {
  display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + ul li {
  display:list-item;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

You can use a `<input type="checkbox"/>` to change the visibility of the items.

---

You can also use the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) with [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) (other way to calculate the hidden items):

```css
ul li:not(:nth-child(-n + 4)) {
  display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + ul li {
  display:list-item;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: and this is too good  ":not(:nth-child(-n + 4))" for learn other way

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `:not()` pseudo class and `:nth-child()`.

```css
ul li:not(:nth-child(-n + 4)) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is easy, you should read about CSS.

use this:

```
ul li:nth-child(n+4){display:none;}
```